# How to avoid emptying space after hiding a fragment

Tags: android, fragment, hide, show

I want to show next step after completing current step to user. For that i'm using fragments. So i'm hiding next area of window on completion of the first task, but when I hides one fragment and shows next fragment it takes all the area of both fragmnets. How to avoid this ?

Code to hide fragment is as following :

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
                android.R.animator.fade_out);
        if(flag == 1){
            ft.show(fragment);
        }else ft.hide(fragment);

        ft.commit();
```

Comment: How are you "hiding" your fragment? Post your code

Comment: Post code and clarify more..

Comment: Set visibility of the container view of fragment with `View.GONE`

Comment: Code attached with the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way would be to replace your `FirstFragment` with your `SecondFragment` like this:

```
SecondFragment secondFragment= new SecondFragment();
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);
ft.replace(R.id.yourlayout, secondFragment).commit();
```

Comment: My screen contains three fragments and so the three parts. 1. Upper half of the screen, 2. lower left of the screen and 3. lower right of the screen. I dont want to replace fragment, just want to hide first after completion of the task and then display next to indicate next task for the user.

Comment: You can either do that with two fragment and replace them when the task is completed, or use `View.Visible` and `View.Gone`.

Answer (score 0):

wrap   inside the other layout like:

```
<LinearLayout>
  <Fragment>
  </Fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

and set `linearlayout.setvisibility(1)`

I did this and it is working, but is it really a good way to program ?